# MVVM showDialog with owner and close when background worker finishes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm just trying to get a grasp of MVVM pattern in WPF (currently without any framework).

**Scenario:**

I have a main window, I click a button "Start work" that is bound to some command in the viewmodel. Progress dialog should open with "Cancel" button, it should show on the center of the owner window(so I need to pass the owner), I press cancel and I invoke "CancelAsync" method on background worker.

The principle of MVVM is that the view model should never know anything about the view and in my case I'm violating this rule.

**Code-behind (No MVVM) solution:**

Main window part:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    progressWindow = new ProgressWindow(backgroundWorker);
    progressWindow.Owner = this;
    progressWindow.ShowDialog();
}

private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressWindow.Close();
}
```

Progress window part:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}
```

**My attempt to convert this code to MVVM (this is wrong)**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ICommand DoSomething { get; }
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

    private PleaseWaitView pleaseWaitView;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

        var pleaseWaitViewModel = new PleaseWaitViewModel(backgroundWorker);
        pleaseWaitView = new PleaseWaitView();
        pleaseWaitView.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        pleaseWaitView.DataContext = pleaseWaitViewModel;

        DoSomething = new ActionCommand<object>(DoSomethingImpl);
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        pleaseWaitView.Close();
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Some work
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    private void DoSomethingImpl(object parameter)
    {
        pleaseWaitView.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

How to solve this? I did what I wanted in code-behind in a matter of 20 minutes, I wanted to try MVVM pattern and it takes me few hours to solve simple problem.

I was looking at some solutions with EventAggregator but that requires using a framework like Prism, Caliburn.Micro. So I get some kind of communication between VM and the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an interface to MainViewModel which contains the needed methods

```
interface IMainView
{
    void Init(PleaseWaitViewModel viewModel);
    void ShowDialog();
    void Close();
}

public class MainViewModel
{
     private IMainView _view;
     public MainViewModel(IMainView view)
     {
         _view = view;


        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
        BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

        var pleaseWaitViewModel = new PleaseWaitViewModel(backgroundWorker);
        _view.Init(pleaseWaitViewModel);
     }

    private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _view.Close();
}

private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Some work
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

private void DoSomethingImpl(object parameter)
{
    _view.ShowDialog();
}
}
```

Comment: I really don't like the idea of having interface for the view.

Comment: ok, i deal with mvvm for a while and it's a simple approach. Even for 
unit test. But you can take a look at Messenger from MvvmLight

Comment: @Lone Wolf McQuade, it is the best solution, dot. The "messenger" solution means that you are "jumping" the code just like the "goto" statement in old languages, we don't want that. Using an interface means that you can implement the "MessageBox" on any platform, and you are not using an specific view platform instruction.

Comment: @Luis I'm using background worker because in my work I have a requirement to support Windows XP. And async/await are not possible without additional dependency

Comment: So I can't really use 4.5+ features in some projects

Comment: Messenger solution seems ugly to me as well. In MVVM it's all about abstracting things to be able to plug some testable interface when you want to unit test so maybe this isn't bad because you do things without touching the view code at all.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this one problem. Not sure which is the cleanest one yet. Another solution would be to make some sort of IViewService or IViewManager and map view models with the views so you just pass any viewmodel and it finds the view and creates it.

Comment: So the viewmodel doesn't know anything about the view or it's type and implementation of view manager takes care of that.

Comment: Also I think when you don't use unit testing at all and just use mvvm for the structure then I see no reason not to use the view directly from viewmodel. Some would say it's an anti pattern

Comment: The ViewModel doesn't know anything about the View. The view knows about the VM. It is not only antipattern, it is about future changes in code, it is better to follow the mvvm pattern.

Comment: Take a look at MVVM Dialogs, you can either be inspired by it or use it directly. My perspective as the author of the library is that opening dialogs is something that should just work, and not something you should spend time on. You have real problems to solve, and opening dialogs shouldn't be one of them.

Comment: @LoneWolfMcQuade When you want to implement mvvm you have to look for some behaviour, like how to show a window. And i think mvvm comes with services. So for me the real name is mvvm and services (through interfaces). I think interface is the best solution because you cannot use the viewModel without all he need to work, with delegate you can forget to implement actions.

Comment: @CédricB what do you mean by "with delegate you can forget to implement actions". Any example?

Comment: I think service/interface is the most elegant solution than using event aggregator or messenger now after some thinking

Comment: @LoneWolfMcQuade Take a look at the example under if you forget to implement the action and you have many delegate then how are going to deal with lots of issues. With interface all the methods you have to implement are visibles faster

Answer (score 1):

Messenger approach

```
public class PersonsViewModel
{
        private RelayCommand _addPersonCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand AddPersonCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _addPersonCommand ?? (_addPersonCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    () =>
                    {
                        Action<Person> callback = (person) =>
                        {
                            _persons.Add(person);
                            RaisePropertyChanged("Persons");
                        };

                        Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessageAction<Person>>(new NotificationMessageAction<Person>(this, new Person(), "myNotification", callback), this);          
                    }));
            }
        }
}

private PersonsViewModel _viewModel = null;
public PersonsView()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     DataContext = _viewModel = new PersonsViewModel();
     Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessageAction<Person>>(this, _viewModel, message => 
     {
          if(message.Notification == "myNotification")
          {
                Person person = (Person)message.Target;
                Action<Person> callback = message.Execute;
                ModalView view = new ModalView(person);
                if(true == view.ShowDialog())
                {
                      callback.Invoke(view.Person);
                }
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: What about, besides of these 2 approaches creating a delegate on view model, and setting this delegate to some method of my view, inside the view?

Comment: From what I see, in case of this project MVVM just overcomplicates things.

Comment: Yes you can also set a delegate, there is other approach like attached behavior.

Comment: Mvvm is great because of separation and unit testing. In the beginning it's seems complicated but once you have chosen your scenario it's ok. And for teams it made code more similar

Answer (score 1):

Action property on view model approach 
1) Add action property on the viewmodel
2) Wire it up in the view code behind 
3) Invoke action it in the viewmodel logic where needed

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    namespace WpfApp1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                // Wire up CancelAction in the View
                var windowToClose = new Window();
                var castedContext = (ViewModel) DataContext;
                castedContext.CancelAction = () => windowToClose.Close();
            }
        }

        public class ViewModel
        {
            private ICommand _doSomethingCommand;
            public Action CancelAction { get; set; }

            public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_doSomethingCommand != null)
                        return _doSomethingCommand;

                    _doSomethingCommand = new MyCommandImplementation(() =>
                    {
                        // Perform Logic

                        // If need to cancel - invoke cancel action
                        CancelAction.Invoke();
                    });
                    return _doSomethingCommand;
                }
            }
        }

        // Stubbed out for the sake of complete code
        public class MyCommandImplementation : ICommand
        {
            public MyCommandImplementation(Action action)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        }
    }
```